# best way to use session without cookies via ge

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I am using PHP, for some reason and I want to switch sessions from using cookies to string, so what is best way to use Sessions with cookies by using GET variable? Should we need to use session id in GET variable? Or some other things? If I will use GET variable with session id inside get then how will I get session according to that session id? If some one have idea then please share.

thanks in advance.

Comment: it is highly recommended not to allow the use of GET variables for passing session ids. imagine your user is logged into your site, and then posts a link to your site on the internet or something. now anyone who has that link may pretend they are logged in as that user. not to mention, it makes ugly urls.

Comment: yes I am aware of this so I will definitely look for its solution also. If you know some other better ways then please tell me but unfortunately I have to do it with get

Comment: I am developing a fb app. and IE8 (depending upon user's  security setting) is adding site to untrusted and blocking cookies so my client want it to have sessions then managable via GET, thats why..

Comment: Just another comment on passing the cookies using GET this gets stored in a number of places around the browser like history and is easier to eavesdrop on.  From a security perspective it is generally inadvisable. If you insist on doing it this way it might be worth investing some time in making sure that the cookie is more secure.  Some ideas like making sure it is not transferable (include the user IP as part of the cookie). Making sure the user has the option to log out. Making sure there can only be one concurrent session for a user and having a short cookie time out on the server will hlp

Comment: @Rob Thanks for comment Rob, I understand it isn't good but when I posted that question more than 1 year ago, this was what one of my client asked to do so. So I asked that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Apache,

```
php_flag session.use_trans_sid = 1
php_value session.use_only_cookies 0
```

However there are [good reasons why cookies are better](http://www.ragepank.com/articles/26/disable-phpsessid/).

Comment: I know cookies are better but if I have not the option to use cookies then what will be the solution?

Comment: As far as I know, if you do the above, it will use cookies by default, and if they are not available it will fall back to using $_GET strings. Sessions are accessible from $_SESSION no matter how they are set.

Comment: And why would using cookies not be an option? I don't think any browsers will disable sessions cookies by default, and if the user manually disables them, well, not many other sites are going to work for them either.

Comment: I am developing a fb app. and IE8 (depending upon user's  security setting) is adding site to untrusted and blocking cookies so my client want it to have sessions then managable via GET, thats why..

Comment: do I need to do the above in apache httpd.conf ?

Comment: In httpd.conf, in .htaccess or by using PHP's ini_set() should all work I believe.

Comment: @Hafiz If your client is asking you to run sessions via $_GET (querystring) then it is your responsibility as a developer to inform him of the huge security risk that would represent to his application.

Comment: @George Velez: He is also a programmer and aware of it but he still want it , if user don't  have cookies enable